# function says returning boolean when i want to return anonymous type

Tags: javascript

So i have this settings check function

```
function areConfigSettingsProper() {
    var configurationLimits = {
        minItems: 10,
    }

    var configSettingsProper = _.every(storageConfigurationViewModel.configSettings.data(),
        function(configSetting) {
            if (configSetting.Enabled)
            {
                //Rounds limits
                if (configSetting.items < configurationLimits.minItems)
                {
                    return {
                        isValid: false,
                        message: "To few items in storage"
                    };
            }

            return {
                isValid: true,
                message: ""
            };
        });

    return configSettingsProper;
}
```

But this is said as it is returning a boolean still and therefore i cant access my message when i try to use it like this

```
const checkConfigSettings = areConfigSettingsProper();

            if (checkConfigSettings.isValid) {
                showSummary();
            }
            else {
                showWarningWithConfirmation(checkConfigSettings.message);
            }
```

But this doesnt show any message at all so for some reason i cant access it properly. So obviously i am doing something wrong. How should i handle this in a good practice? this is all done in an cshtml file

Comment: You may want to read up on how `_.every` works: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#every

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do but maybe you're looking for `_.map` or `_.reduce`. `_.every` just returns a boolean if all elements pass a predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `configSettingsProper` funtion is actually calling `every`, not the function you hve passed as an argument. The return type of this function is `boolean`, hence your result.

Also, your declared function might not work as you expect it. `every` will check the return of this function for *truthyness*. Since you are returning an `object` there (your boolean value is just one of its properties), you can expect the result of `configSettingsProper` to be always `true`.